# WooCommerce "add to cart" missing

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have recently included a Woocommerce installation to my website.  My theme doesn't seem to be well optimised for it but it's particularly good for displaying my photography.

The problem I have is that I have different print sizes selectable and the menu works but when selecting an option the add to cart button doesn't appear.

My site is located here
[Product with no "add to cart" option](http://russelljd.co.uk/product/ladybower-plughole/)

I'm just a bit lost with how I can make it work within this theme but not sure what's causing the button to not appear.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you get this working? I can see the add to cart option now?

Comment: I had to use a different theme as that one simply would not work. I eventually got the button to show but it wouldn't then add the item to the cart

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a known issue with some themes. Usually it's a plugin that is preventing the add to cart from showing. First backup your site, then deactivate each plugin, one by one and check your product pages to see if add to cart has returned. For me the plugin was redux, for others it has been the slider plugin, perhaps start with those if you have them. C